# How to implement one interface contains generics through javassist

Tags: java, generics, javassist

I want to generate a dynamic class to do something, such as:

```java
/**
 * Type Converter.
 *
 * @author sunhao(sunhao.java@gmail.com)
 * @version V1.0
 * @createTime 2015-2-9 22:07
 */
public interface StringParse<V> {
    /**
     * Convert
     *
     * @param str data to Convert
     * @return
     */
    public V parse(String str);
}
```

Now I want to generate a dynamic bean. As we all see, this interface need a generics, like the following code:

```java
CtClass ctClass = cp.makeClass("message.utils.StringParse$" + System.currentTimeMillis());
//create a interface that contain a generics like given type *dest*
CtClass ctInterface = cp.makeInterface("message.utils.StringParse<" + dest.getName() + ">");
ctClass.addInterface(ctInterface);
```

But when executed, the above code gave an exception:

```java
javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: message/utils/StringParse<java/lang/Integer>
```

I think that javassist may not support generating generics. Am I right, or can someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: There are no generics at run time.

Comment: I found that code can run correctly, even without generics. does javassist not support generics?

Comment: As @BoristheSpider said on class level there is very little to none left of generics due to type erasure. In other words generics in Java assist you for type safety only prior to compilation. See what [javaassist has to say about it](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) to achieve this:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .makeInterface()
  .name("StringParse")
  .typeVariable("V")
  .defineMethod("parse",
      TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.typeVariable("V").build(), 
      Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .withParameters(String.class)
  .withoutCode()
  .make();
```